# is there any method in java which has the same function as ReadInt16() in Visual C++

Tags: java, visual-c++

is there any method in java which has the same function as ReadInt16() in Visual C++. I have to read a binary file in which numerical data is stored in 16 bit form.

Answer (score 5):

If you're reading from a java.io.InputStream, you probably want something like this:

```
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
short myInt16 = dataInputStream.readShort();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, int in Java is fixed at 32 bits.  But short is 16 bits; maybe you can use that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Sounds like you'll have to do some work on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `RandomAccessR`'s [readInt16()](http://www.extex.org/snapshot/javadoc/org/extex/util/file/random/RandomAccessR.html#readInt16%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that Java uses big endian by default.  Many MS based systems use little endian so you may want to use ByteBuffer instead.

A simple way to do this for files less than 2 GB is to memory map the file and use order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) You can also randomly access this file using position(pos).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use `ByteBuffer` to read binary numeric data, especially if you are using c/c++, because default byte order of Java is big endian, while it's little endian in c/c++.

```
byte[] bin_data = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap (bin_data);
bb.order (ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
System.out.println (String.format("0x%04X", bb.getShort ());  // 0x0201
System.out.println (String.format("0x%04X", bb.getShort ());  // 0x0403
```